# Change local date in PyQt application

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

How to modify local date in PyQt application (i needed to change it on linux and win platform)? E.g.:

```
>>> date_now = QtCore.QDate.currentDate()
>>> print date_now
>>> PyQt4.QtCore.QDate(2014, 3, 3)

...some code for change current date

>>> date_now = QtCore.QDate.currentDate()
>>> print date_now
>>> PyQt4.QtCore.QDate(2012, 1, 1)
```

Notice: external system date must not change.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. Why don't you create a new `QDate` with the date you want to use?

Comment: @Andy Becаuse i want use julian calendar system in my application. I want change calendar systems dynamicly between Gregorian and Julianan.

Comment: @to_night. Have you read the Qt docs section on the [Use of Gregorian and Julian Calendars](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#use-of-gregorian-and-julian-calendars), and are you aware of the [toJulianDay](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdate.html#toJulianDay) method?

Comment: @ekhumoro.    toJulianDay returns [Julian Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), but i need to change calendar system in the whole applications, like [http://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kdecore/html/classKCalendarSystemJulian.html](http://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kdecore/html/classKCalendarSystemJulian.html). How it made?

Comment: @to_night. It's made by creating your own `JulianDate` class (just like KDE) and using `toJulianDay`/`fromJulianDay` to make the necessary conversions. If you want nore details, take a look at the [KCalendarSystemJulian soure code](http://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kdecore/html/kcalendarsystemjulian_8cpp_source.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monkey-patch `QDate`:

```
QtCore.QDate.currentDate = lambda: QtCore.QDate(2012, 1, 1)
```

Which might lead to inconsistencies somewhere else.

---

Working example:

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Oct  9 2013, 14:50:09) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> QtCore.QDate.currentDate()
PyQt4.QtCore.QDate(2014, 3, 3)
>>> QtCore.QDate.currentDate = lambda: QtCore.QDate(2012, 1, 1)
>>> QtCore.QDate.currentDate()
PyQt4.QtCore.QDate(2012, 1, 1)
>>>
```

---

For python2.7:

```
class PatchedQDate (QtCore.QDate):
    @classmethod
    def currentDate (cls):
        return QtCore.QDate (2012, 1, 1)

QtCore.QDate = PatchedQDate
```

Comment: It not work on python 2.7: `TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called with QDate instance as first argument (got nothing instead`.